# CloudConvert API - When converting PDF to PNG, how do I know how many pages have been converted

Tags: cloudconvert

When using CloudConvert to convert a PDF to PNGs, ie, there is more then one page in the PDF, CloudConvert will add a '-1' / '-2' to the end of each fileName ( prior to the file extension, ie 'my-image-1.png' ). CloudConvert is creating a separate PNG for each page.  BUT how can I find this out from the API ? ( I'm using the official node-api ). I do not know the number of pages before I start the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I found it!  In the response to each request ( job ) there is an array of tasks, the export task has a results Object with a files Array and within this there will be the filenames created. I was using export/s3.